# Почему значения выборки удваиваются?

Tags: sql

Вводя запрос

```
   SELECT
    `p`.`name` AS NAME,
    `pa`.`atribute_name` AS `Atribute`,
    CONCAT_WS(" ", pd.value, pv.value) AS VALUE
FROM
    `products` AS `p`,
    `product_atributes` AS `pa`
LEFT JOIN `product_atribute_value_decimal` AS `pd`
ON
    `pd`.`atribute_id` = `pa`.`atribute_id`
LEFT JOIN `product_atribute_value_varchar` AS `pv`
ON
    `pv`.`atribute_id` = `pa`.`atribute_id`
WHERE
    pd.value OR pv.value IS NOT NULL
```

появляется вот такой результат

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ScMsC.png]

Но у каждого товара свое значение, и не понятно почему отображается так много значений.
В чем может быть проблема?

Связи таблиц:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Пытаюсь создать еще одну связь

```
product_atribute_value_decimal.product_id = products.product_id
```

но появляется следующая ошибка:

> #1054 - Неизвестный столбец 'product_atribute_value_decimal.product_id' в 'on clause'

хотя такие таблицы и столбцы у меня есть

Comment: Пропущены связи по полям `product_id`.

Comment: `pd.value OR pv.value IS NOT NULL` — сомневаюсь что сервер вас правильно поймет